# Alternative for DatastoreHelper Java class in Google Cloud Datastore v1 API

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-datastore

In the Datastore v1Beta2 API version, DatastoreHelper was a public class, and we rely on member functions like getOptionsFromEnv(), getComputeEngineCredential(), makeFilter() and makeValue(). Looks like that class is now private in the v1 API. What's the equivalent class that will provide us access to those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those methods are still public in [google-cloud-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore) library:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/java/datastore/src/main/java/com/google/datastore/v1/client/DatastoreHelper.java

`getComputeEngineCredential()` was removed, but you can use [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) instead, which supports getting a credential from Compute Engine.

Comment: Thanks. I realized DatastoreHelper is present in two different JAR files, and it's public in one of them and private in the other. I mistakenly looked at the wrong JAR file.

Comment: Instead of calling getComputeEngineCredential( which doesn't exist anymore), am I correct that we need to set an env var called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the correct JSON file?

Comment: Application Default Credentials looks for credentials (in order) in several places, and uses the first one it finds. If you're running on Compute Engine, you don't need to set anything; it will use the built-in service account. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork